# Group by Age Range based on Date

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have a structure:

```
[
            {
                "_id": {
                    "question": "Voluptatem perferendis voluptas ex.",
                    "option": "Eligendi ratione fuga autem fugiat velit quo.",
                    "user_dob": {
                        "$date": {
                            "$numberLong": "1306281600000"
                        }
                    }
                },
                "total_votes": 1
            },
            {
                "_id": {
                    "question": "Voluptatem perferendis voluptas ex.",
                    "option": "Eligendi ratione fuga autem fugiat velit quo.",
                    "user_dob": {
                        "$date": {
                            "$numberLong": "22118400000"
                        }
                    }
                },
                "total_votes": 1
            }, {...}, ...
]
```

I need to group data by user_age_group. I have a predefined age gropus:

```
'age_groups' => [
        '0-14 years' => ['from' => 0, 'to' => 14],
        '15-24 years' => ['from' => 15, 'to' => 24],
        '25-54 years' => ['from' => 25, 'to' => 54],
        '55-64 years' => ['from' => 55, 'to' => 64],
        '65 years and over' => ['from' => 65, 'to' => 999]
    ]
```

Or even let's say, I have an already calcualted $from and $to date variables for all of these age_groups.

In the end of the ends I need to get the next structure:

```
[
            {
                "_id": "Voluptatem perferendis voluptas ex.",
                "options": [
                    {
                        "option": "Vero rerum qui animi quia assumenda.",
                        "votes_by_age": [
                            {
                                "age_group": "25-54 years",
                                "total_votes": 1
                            },
                            {
                                "age_group": "55-64 years",
                                "total_votes": 1
                            },
                            {
                                "age_group": "65 years and over",
                                "total_votes": 5
                            }
                        ]
                    }, {...}, ...
]
```

It seems I need to add some calculated property and then add group by it. But I don't have no idea how I can do this... Hope somenone can help me with that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do the translation here using the [`$switch`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/switch/) operator, comparing the current date to the [`$year`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/year/) from the stored date.

In order to nest the arrays you will call [`$group`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) several times:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  { "$group": {
    "_id": {
      "question": "$_id.question",
      "option": "$_id.option",
      "age_group": {
        "$let": {
          "vars": { 
            "age": {
              "$subtract": [
                { "$year": new Date() },
                { "$year": "$_id.user_dob" }
              ]
            }
          },
          "in": {
            "$switch": {
              "branches": [
                {
                  "case": { "$lte": [ "$$age", 14 ] },
                  "then": "0-14 years",
                },
                {
                  "case": { "$lte": [ "$$age", 24 ] },
                  "then": "15-24 years",
                },
                {
                  "case": { "$lte": [ "$$age", 54 ] },
                  "then": "25-54 years",
                },
                {
                  "case": { "$lte": [ "$$age", 64 ] },
                  "then": "55-64 years",
                }
              ],
              "default": "65 years and over"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "total_votes": { "$sum": "$total_votes" }
  }},
  { "$group": {
    "_id": {
      "question": "$_id.question",
      "option": "$_id.option"
    },
    "votes_by_age": {
      "$push": {
        "age_group": "$_id.age_group",
        "total_votes": "$total_votes"
      }
    },
    "total_votes": { "$sum": "$total_votes" }
  }},
  { "$group": {
    "_id": "$_id.question",
    "options": {
      "$push": {
        "option": "$_id.option",
        "votes_by_age": "$votes_by_age",
        "total_votes": "$total_votes"
      }
    },
    "total_votes": { "$sum": "$total_votes" }
  }}
])
```

Which outputs from the supplied data:

```
{
        "_id" : "Voluptatem perferendis voluptas ex.",
        "options" : [
                {
                        "option" : "Eligendi ratione fuga autem fugiat velit quo.",
                        "votes_by_age" : [
                                {
                                        "age_group" : "25-54 years",
                                        "total_votes" : 1
                                },
                                {
                                        "age_group" : "0-14 years",
                                        "total_votes" : 1
                                }
                        ],
                        "total_votes" : 2
                }
        ],
        "total_votes" : 2
}
```

Note that part of the question appears to contain PHP code, so instead of `new Date()` for a JavaScript based shell that would be [`MongoDB\BSON\UTCDatetime(time() * 1000)`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.mongodb-bson-utcdatetime.php), using PHP `time()` and the MongoDB driver function to wrap that as a BSON Date.

The [`$let`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/let/) is so you don't repeat the same expression every time when it is referenced within the [`$switch`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/switch/) cases. The `"vars"` are declared and referenced via the `$$` prefix, as in `"$$age"` as shown.

Each [`$group`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) progressively removes a part of the key, so things are accumulated and then moved into an array via [`$push`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/push/) as keys are moved. The additional `total_votes` at each level should make it clear how this accumulation is working

Comment: Thank. One addition. If user.dob is not isset, I need 'no age provided' group with count result.

Comment: @DenysSiebov This is not a "write my code to order service". You have an answer to the question you asked. If you have another question then [Ask a new Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask)